Solar panel 400W / 36v to battery 12V
I have received a good offer for a 400V to 36v solar panel (40V ~ 10.1Amps open circuit).
My question is, I already have a 12V solar chargers and a 12V battery.
I want to pair this with a 12V battery, since I already have some devices that only run at 12V.
My specific question: Is it better to buy one or more step down modules to go down from 36V ~ 40V of the solar panel to 12V (for each device that uses 12V), or better to buy a powerful one that goes down from 36V ~ 40V to 15V and from there it goes to the 12V charger and from there to the individual battery(s).
These images might help to understand.
Scenario 1: The step down module just after the 400w/36V panel.
Scenario 2: The step down module after output to the battery.


Thanks in advance.

those pwm charge controllers aren't supposed to be used with lithium batteries. Just get a cheap MPPT one and don't use any DC-DC converters.

Neither one of those is right. The second diagram definitely won't work; the first one kind of almost works except that
A) The battery charger probably wants to see 16-20V input, not 12. A fancy one might be able to boost, but most don't.
B) The MPPT function of the charger won't work when you put a regulator between it and the solar panel, and things may break down messily when there's less sun.
The correct solution is simply to buy a solar charge controller that's made for 12V batteries, but which supports 50V or more on the input. We're not allowed to do product recommendation here, but there are plenty of those out there if you look for them. They may be switchable between 12V and 24V batteries (or even more, like 48V), but as long as there's a 12V option you're good. A 40 amp model would be able to use the full capacity of your panel; a 30 amp one would come reasonably close.

Thanks Hobbs. Is there another way to manage it? Reusing my chargers and battery?
